# Simple JPQL query not working in OpenJPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, openjpa

The following query that is working perfectly fine when I am using hibernate as the JPA provider is not working with OpenJPA:

```
entityManager.createQuery(
        "select ord from Order ord " +
        "where symbol = :symbol")
    .setParameter("symbol", symbol)
    .getResultList();
```

The error returned is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid unbound variable "symbol" in query
```

Am I doing something wrong in my query that OpenJPA does not like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to change:"where symbol = :symbol" to :

```
 "where ord.symbol = :symbol"
```

Or, use positional parameters:

```
"where ord.symbol = ?1"

  .setParameter(1, symbol)
```

Hope that helps.